# Can I add a C# class in visual studio as resource so I can add to new projects conveniently?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I create various samples with WPF where I always need to add the same base class for MVVM classes. I always have to go to one of the older projects, find that and add to new project.

Is there a way I can add this to visual studio as reusable component so whenever I need it in a new project, I can just add that? It would just a c# class.

Ideally it would be an option of reusable components in the menu below when I am adding something new to project but if there is any other way would do!

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

Comment: Project templates would work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write the class then export as item template...
Let you want to add Hello World! class in your every project.

Go to File->Export Template->Item Template...
Then select your class to export....

Now whenever you want to add this class to your project click add new item.

Comment: That's what I was looking for but the "Export Template" option is under Project menu in VS2019.

Answer (score 2):

I would just create a class library and share that. Or you could create a project template that has the files you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Serialization and deserialization of  classes

[serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/basic-serialization)

Answer (score -1):

There is handy plugin: [Add New File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.AddNewFile).

Usage:

**Shift + F2**, name new file with `.cs` extension and class will be created.

Comment: It seems to be add new file, not an existing stock file?